# Container format requires global headers

Tags: ffmpeg, codec

Using this FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg-20160127-git-9079e99
```

With [this file](http://jplayer.org/audio/m4a/Miaow-02-Hidden.m4a), if I run this command:

```
ffmpeg -i Miaow-02-Hidden.m4a -c copy outfile.m4a
```

I get this message:

```
[ipod @ 0000000000694500] Codec for stream 0 does not use global headers but
container format requires global headers
```

How can I resolve this warning?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This issue was fixed with [commit 955b818](//github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/commit/955b818):

```
commit 955b818cf947473ec94a3fe8aa7f408b119fbbc9
Author: Clément Bœsch <clement@stupeflix.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 1 16:48:45 2016 +0200

    ffmpeg: switch to codecpar
```

You can suppress the warning on older version like so:

```
ffmpeg -i Miaow-02-Hidden.m4a -c copy -flags global_header outfile.m4a
```

[Example](//github.com/svnpenn/a/blob/db3e32f/music/music-download.sh#L67-L68)

Comment: You should prefix a `+` before `global_header` so that any flags set internally aren't overridden.

Comment: Are you saying that this is just a warning and can be ignored?

Comment: Does the same requirement apply to formats such as HLS and DASH, ie can one get away without using `-flags +global_header`?